# A website sends account credential field as "empty"

Tags: passwords, websites

One of Finland's largest banks, [S-Pankki](https://www.s-pankki.fi/), seems to use some uncommon method to send the username field. At least Firefox's password manager doesn't detect the entered username and I've also experienced the same with Lastpass. Why does this happen?

[image: Firefox password manager prompt]

Sadly [the website](https://www.s-pankki.fi/) isn't available in English--enter account credentials (you don't need to have an account, use fake data) by pressing the orange "verkkopankkiin" button (followed by clicking "kirjaudu"/<kbd>Enter</kbd>) if you have to test in order to answer the question.
"Käyttäjätunnus" means username, "salasana" equals password.

Comment: I don't know what tags to use, please edit if necessary.

Comment: On that site the username field is not a regular textbox but a password-type field, so I suppose Firefox doesn't recognize it as such.

Comment: @Arminius: Can this be considered as a design flaw?

Comment: its so shoulder surfers can't get the login name. well-intentioned but silly and annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there is the technical explanation that is already covered in the comments: The website seems to use the input type password, not plain text - hence password managers that search for a plain text/password combination fail to recognize this field.

Then there is the wider question of why this would be done.

In this case, this is a bank, which often use your account number (a somewhat sensitive information) as a login name. Using not a plain text field may be to keep (as the comments mentioned) shoulder surfers from peeking your user name.

Yet, this might as well be an attempt on compliance. There are some regulations that do prohibit saving user name/password combination as to avoid problems that might arise from saving passwords:

- People tend to forget passwords more often when they do not type then regularly
- Malware might extract those saved passwords when they are not handled with care

Those points are not all too valid - the first one even encourages password reuse when no password manager may be used, which is horrible.

The second point is somewhat reasonable with respect to the default setting of most browsers to save such data somewhat unprotected (e.g. without a master password for the vault).

Nonetheless, some regulators do stick to those guidelines and while there exist [better ways of complying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality), this might very well be an attempt of doing so.